# Transpose array to rows using PIG latin

Tags: apache-pig

How to convert ARRY elements in BAG to multiple rows  eg: below

My input:

tuple, ARRAY_ELEM
(32,{(1,emp,3271409712),(2,emp,3271409712)})

Output
(32,1,emp,3271409712)
(32,2,emp,3271409712)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to call FLATTEN twice. 
Note, FLATTEN on a tuple just elevates each field in the tuple to a top-level field.
FLATTEN on bag produces a cross product of every record in the bag with all of the other expressions in GENERATE.

```
A = load 'test.txt' using PigStorage() as (a0:int, t1:(a1:int, b1 {(a3:int,a4:chararray,a5:chararray)}));
describe A;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(t1);  
describe B;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE a1, FLATTEN(b1);
describe C;
dump C;
```

Output

```
A: {a0: int,t1: (a1: int,b1: {(a3: int,a4: chararray,a5: chararray)})}
B: {t1::a1: int,t1::b1: {(a3: int,a4: chararray,a5: chararray)}}
C: {t1::a1: int,t1::b1::a3: int,t1::b1::a4: chararray,t1::b1::a5: chararray}
(32,1,emp,3271409712)
(32,2,emp,3271409712)
```